# How To Test New Timing Chain Before Engine Closed?

Tags: engine, vw, crankshaft, timing-chain

How much **crankshaft turns** to match the **marks** again?

**Car:VW CC**
**Engine: TSI 1.8**
**Engine Code:CDAA**
**Year:2009**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need **344** crankshaft **turns** to match the marks again.

Comment: Good work ... for your health, did the timing change? Or was it ok?

Comment: @SolarMike This engine probably has a bent valve(s), i haven't checked yet.

Answer (score 7):

For a four-stroke engine you need to rotate 2 turns of the crankshaft to get to the same position.

Comment: Thanks for reply as i see two turns of the crankshaft is not enough at all.

Comment: @FredjAJad - Mike is spot on. That's exactly what you're supposed to do ... two complete revolutions of the crankshaft. That will get you one complete revolution of your camshaft(s). Remember, the belt/chain will not line up again (not for a bunch of revolutions), it's the timing marks on the cam sprocket and crankshaft which matters. You don't want the chain/belt to line up again (if that's what you're doing) so that you don't get sympathetic wear in it (same belt/chain tooth against same sprocket groove over and over again). This will wear out the belt too fast, so is designed so it doesn't.

Comment: @FredjAJad - No. I'm saying the belt/chain itself won't align again with the timing marks. You have to rely on the sprocket marks and review them against the alignment marks on the block/cover surfaces. Do not expect the same spot on the belt/chain to align again with the same tooth on the sprocket if you have marked the belt/chain expecting them to align again ... it just won't happen any time soon. To be "in time" is for the crankshaft and cams to be in coordination. The timing marks aligns it correctly, while the belt keeps it that way. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Thanks a lot for your help, now I understand what you tried to say to me, but sure There's magic formula to find out the number of crankshaft turns!

Comment: @FredjAJad : the magic formula you refer to is that there are 4 strokes necessary to complete the cycle , these are induction, compression, power and exhaust. Each time the crankshaft rotes once any piston goes up and down. Therefore to get a piston to go up twice (for compression and exhaust) and down twice (for induction and power) to give the 4 strokes the crankshaft has to rotate twice.

Comment: It will take MANY turns before the chain ends up perfectly back on the timing marks.  There is no reason to go beyond 2 though.  If it was lined up wrong, and you were going to contact a valve, you would feel it within 2 complete turns.  turning it 47 times to get the factory marks lined back up isn't neccesary.

Comment: Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 and Zshoulders Thanks a lot both of you, @Zshoulders how did you know that its must be turned 47 times to match the marks again? did you count teeth on chain and teeth on crankshaft sprocket? I know that the number of turns would be huge maybe 200+ i think

Comment: @Fredj A Jad I didn't, 47 was just a random big number I picked to illustrate that it would take a lot of turns

Comment: @FredjAJad - Two things: 1) It takes a lot of turns to get the chain/belt back to jump street; 2) It really doesn't matter. You only need to spin the crank around twice to realign all the timing marks to know you're golden.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Thank you I really appreciate your help. I am grateful for everything you've taught me, thanks again